# Why is "Edit in SharePoint Designer" opening in Notepad

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm following this example - [link here](http://blog.henryong.com/2010/06/08/how-to-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-page-layouts-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/)

I've gone to Master pages and layouts `(_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx)`

I've created a new page layout, when I hover over to click "*Edit in Microsoft SharePoint Designer*" the page opens in notepad

I've clicked on a few other aspx pages in this library and they open in Notepad.

But the master pages I clicked on do open in SP Designer.

**Update with my answer**
I did a Repair on SharePoint Designer and rebooted. Its working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a Repair on SharePoint Designer and rebooted. Its working now.

Answer (score 2):

In IE go to Tools > Internet Options > Programs and see if "Microsoft SharePoint Designer" is selected as the "HTML Editor".

Also try going through Windows Explorer to Tools > Folder Options > File Types; select `ASPX` and set the "Opens With" to SharePoint Designer.

Comment: "HTML Editor" is Word, but I did a Repair on SharePoint Designer and rebooted. Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your SharePoint Designer cache.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/

Then, the Custom workflow will open normally in SharePoint Designer instead of the browser or Notepad.